# Prove that the minimal polynomial of a following block matrix T is the minimal polynomial of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the minimal polynomial of a following block matrix T is the minimal polynomial of A.

A 0

0 A

(I don't know how to key in matrix)

I know this is rather obvious but I can't prove it. I can't think of how to prove that minimal polynomial of A will annihilate T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&A\end{pmatrix}$$
then we have

$$T^k= \begin{pmatrix}A^k&0\\0&A^k\end{pmatrix},\qquad \forall k\in\Bbb N$$
and then for every polynomial $P$ we get

$$P(T)=\begin{pmatrix}P(A)&0\\0&P(A)\end{pmatrix}$$
so every polynomial that annihilates $T$  annihilates also $A$ and the converse is true. The minimality of the degree of the minimal polynomial allows us to conclude.

Comment: can i ask why P(T) will give you P(A) on the other side?

Comment: Write $$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$
and calculate $P(T)$. What do we find?

Comment: You can even prove that $T = \begin{pmatrix}aA&bA\\cA&dA\end{pmatrix}$ has the same minimal polynomial as A if and only if $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalizable